Linking error when type aliasing in dynamic library
I am working on a dynamic library that gets included in a larger project. To be able to run it on Windows and Linux, I wanted to try to set up type aliasing with char and wchar_t depending on if there is UNICODE or not. However, when trying to build the main project I am running into linking errors.
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol.
The import worked previously, but after introducing the type aliasing (see types.h), I start getting linking errors.
export
#pragma once
#if defined(IO_EXPORTS)
#define IO_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define IO_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

types.h
#pragma once
#include "export"

#include <fstream>
#include <string>

namespace IO
{
#ifdef UNICODE
using T = wchar_t;
#define LITERAL(s) L##s
#else
using T = char;
#define LITERAL(s) s
#endif

using String = std::basic_string<T>;
} // namespace IO

manager.h
#pragma once
#include "types.h"
#include "export"

namespace IO
{

class IO_API Manager
{
    Result read(IO::String filename) { // do some stuff };
};

} // namespace IO

The entire linking message:
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct IO::Result __thiscall IO::Manager::read(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> >)" (__imp_?read@Manager@IO@@QAE?AUResult@2@V?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> >::_Construct<1,unsigned short const *>(unsigned short const * const,unsigned int)" (??$_Construct@$00PBG@?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@AAEXQBGI@Z)

Note that I am not 100% sure the type aliasing is causing the issue, but I cannot think of another reason for the error suddenly appear, since I have not changed much else. Could it be possible that it causes the errors, and if so, what do I need to do differently?
Edit:
Since there was questions about Result in the error message, I put it back into the function return value. It is a simple struct containing the a token and an enum, and nothing has changed inside of since it last built succesfully. It is unrelevant to the question (most likely).
result.h
#pragma once

#include "export"
#include "token.h"
#include "types.h"

namespace IO
{
struct IO_API Result
{
    enum class Code
    {
        Ok,
        Unknown
    };

    explicit Result(Code code = Code::Ok, const Token &token = Token()) : code(code), token(token){};

    Code code;
    Token token;
};
} // namespace IO

token.h
#pragma once

#include "export"
#include "types.h"

#include <string>

namespace IO
{

struct IO_API Token
{
    explicit Token(const IO::String &value = LITERAL(""), unsigned int index = 0, unsigned int indent = 0)
        : value(value), index(index), indent(indent){};

    IO::String value;
    unsigned int index, indent;
};
} // namespace IO


What's IO::String and how, if at all, is it related to IO::string?

@IgorTandetnik Sorry, it was a typo from copying the code into the question. It is corrected.

It doesn't make sense to put the implementation into a header for a function that you want to live in the shared library. Does your actual code actually have read implemented in manager.h?

However, when trying to build the main project I am running into linking errors. This sounds like UNICODE is defined when building the DLL but not when building the main project (or vice versa).

It's surprising that wchar_t seems to be a typedef for unsigned short. It's been a dedicated type for a long long time. What MSVC version are you using?  Are you compiling one module but not the other with /Zc:wchar_t[-]

The linker error mentions a function that returns struct IO::Result rather than size_t, and it is very mysterious that a member of std::basic_string is referring to this function. It looks like something is very badly messed up somewhere.

@molbdnilo I know it does, I purposely removed it from the code snippet and put in size_t instead, to prevent getting questions about it.

@AndréLehto if you make up example code snippets that you post then please post the errors that such snippets get. When the snippets get compiler errors like "undefined identifier Result" then those do not illustrate your problem with linking.

@ÖöTiib I get your point. I adjusted the question. I really do not think it brings anything in this case, just more code.

@Scheff'sCat That's it! The library project did not have the flag for UNICODE set. Thank you!

@IgorTandetnik Also the wchar setting was different, which contributed to the issue.
